# C to MIPS - functions and arrays

Tags: mips, mips32

I am trying to translate the following C code to MIPS assembly.

The base address of array is stored in $a0. The variable index is stored in $a1. The variable x is stored in $t0.

```
void ld_array(char array[], int index) {
  x = array[index];
}
```

When index was a defined integer (eg: 5) I had done

```
lbu $t0, 5($a0)
```

However, `lbu $t0, $a1($a0)` is not correct syntax.

Comment: You just have to compute $a1+$a2 and put the result in another register (say $a3). Then you can `lbu $t0,0($a3)`

Comment: Would the same go for the opposite? Eg: if I wanted to do array[index] = x; ?

Comment: To compute the address yes. But  ` array[index]=x` is a store, not a load.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pointer arithmetic to compute the address of the data you are trying to access.

`array[index]` is equivalent to `*(array+index)`. You can do the same thing in mips using the `addu` instruction.

Assuming `$a0` is the array pointer and `$a1` is the index you can use:

```
addu $t0, $a0, $a1 # tmp = array+index
lbu  $t0, ($t0)    # x = *tmp
```

We are using `addu` because it is an unsigned operation since pointers are unsigned words. This means it will not trigger an overflow exception.

Assuming that your array would be an array of words you would use the same approach but first multiply the index by 4 (since words in 32bit are 4 bytes long).

```
sll  $t0, $a1, 2   # index << 2 = index * 4
addu $t0, $a0, $t0 # tmp = array+index
lw   $t0, ($t0)    # x = array[index]
```