# How do I extract bits in a certain position from a word in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I was trying to write a MIPS program that runs similar to the C code below

```
int main{
unsigned int x = 1;
unsigned int y = 11;
while (x < 6) {
int temp = myArray[x];
myArray[x] = myArray[y];
myArray[y] = temp;
x+=2;
y-=2;
}
```

And I have my array defined as below (I can only use .word in this case)

```
    myArray:
        .word 29 17 27 20 25 22 23 24 21 26 19 28
```

I've done the initialization and the ending part but don't know how to do within the loop

```
    li $v0 1
        li $v1 11
        li $v2 6

        loop:
        bge $v0 $v2 loopexit
        
        addi $v0 $v0 1
        sub $v1 $v1 1
```

I'm wondering how can I perform the myArray[x] using MIPS? I'm thinking of bit masking but I'm not sure how to do it with a changing number

Comment: `myArray[x]` is array indexing, selecting which array element (word) to load or store. [C to MIPS - functions and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54858960).  Not shifting to access bits within one word.   Look at C compiler output for MIPS.  ([Tweak mips-gcc output to work with MARS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13052444))

Comment: Or to put it another way, the bits you want to extract are aligned 32-bit chunks from a very wide bit-array.  A special case of bitfield extraction that can and should be done with word loads/stores.